# Why does my program crash when managing this JSON file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

Whenever somebody sends `!setmainchannel`, my program crashes. I am using Node.js with the package discord.js. This is the only problem I have. I don't and can't understand what's wrong, and I would extremely appreciate it if someone could help me out.

`bot.js`:

```js
let Discord = require("discord.js");
let client = new Discord.Client();
let fs = require('fs');

let help = require("./helpembed.json");

var jsonRead = function(filePath){
  fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8', (err, returnJson) => {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      let ret = JSON.parse(returnJson);
      return ret;
    }
  })
}

var jsonWrite = function(filePath, objIn){
  fs.writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(objIn), err => {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  })
}

client.on("message", msg => {
  let time = new Date();
  let cstTimeStamp = `${time.getMonth() + 1}/${time.getDate()}/${time.getFullYear()} ${time.getHours() + 1}:${time.getMinutes()}:${time.getSeconds()}`

  if(msg.content == "!setmainchannel"){
    let mainChannel = msg.mentions.channels.first();

    if(!mainChannel){
      console.log(`${cstTimeStamp} @${msg.author.tag} requested to set a main channel but didn't provide a channel\n`);
      msg.channel.send("There's no channel to set the main to");
    }
    else{
      let currentSettings = jsonRead("./main-channel.json");
      currentSettings.channel = mainChannel;
      jsonWrite("./main-channel.json", currentSettings);
      console.log(`${cstTimeStamp} @${msg.author.tag} set the main channel as ${currentSettings.channel}\n`);
      msg.channel.send(`Set the main channel as ${currentSettings.channel}`);
    }
    
  }
})

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online\n');
});

client.login('Token hidden for safety reasons');
```

`main-channel.json`:

```json
{
    "channel":null
}
```

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: @SuperStormer No error messages happen, but I now realised that the program just does nothing and continues accepting any other commands

Answer (score 0):

First, your bot does nothing because it only reacts `if (msg.content == "!setmainchannel")`. If you provide an argument, like a channel (`!setmainchannel #ch-name`), it won't run as the message's content is not exactly the prefix and the command.

You'll need to fix that first. By removing the prefix and chopping off the arguments, you can get the command itself and check if this exact command is used. (Again, you should not check the whole `message.content`)

Second, you don't wait for the callback inside `readFile` to run. It means, when you try to update `currentSettings.channel`, your `jsonRead()` function has just started to read the file and the `currentSettings` is `undefined`. You won't be able to update its `channel` property.

I've updated both your `jsonWrite` and `jsonRead` functions to return promises and make it easier to use. Check the working code below:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = '!';

client.on('message', async (msg) => {
  // create an args variable that slices off the prefix and splits it into an array
  const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  // create a command variable by taking the first element in the array
  // and removing it from args
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  const cstTimeStamp = new Date().toLocaleString();

  if (command === 'setmainchannel') {
    const mainChannel = msg.mentions.channels.first();
    const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, './main-channel.json');

    if (!mainChannel) {
      console.log(`${cstTimeStamp} ${msg.author.tag} requested to set a main channel but didn't provide a channel\n`);
      return msg.channel.send("There's no channel to set the main to");
    }

    try {
      const currentSettings = await jsonRead(filePath);
      currentSettings.channel = mainChannel;

      jsonWrite(filePath, currentSettings);

      console.log(`${cstTimeStamp} ${msg.author.tag} set the main channel as ${currentSettings.channel}\n`);
      msg.channel.send(`Set the main channel as ${currentSettings.channel}`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
});

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online\n');
});

client.login('Token hidden for safety reasons');

function jsonRead(filePath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8', (err, content) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        try {
          const parsedContent = JSON.parse(content);
          resolve(parsedContent);
        } catch (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

function jsonWrite(filePath, data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(data), (err) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(true);
    });
  });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I see what's going on here. I made the logic react to ONLY `!setmainchannel`, whereas I should've done `if(msg.content.startsWith("!setmainchannel")`!

Comment: No, that's not the only error. Changing just that won't solve the problem and it will still result in a TypeError. See my answer for more details.